# Simultaneous vanishing of quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields, quadratic-forms

When does a system of quadratic forms
$$Q_i(x)=q_{i1}x_1^2+\dotsb+q_{in}x_n^2,\ i\in[1,m]$$
have a nontrivial common zero? By the Chevalley–Warning theorem, $n>2m$ is a sufficient condition, but I need a more precise criterion; what happens if $n\le 2m$?

I am sure this has been studied; references or pointers will be appreciated.

The coefficients $q_{ij}$ of the forms $Q_i$ come from a field $K$, the finite fields of characteristic $3$ being of particular interest for me.

Comment: If all your quadratic forms are diagonal, as it seems in your question, you can set $y_i=x_i^2$. Then you obtain a linear system, whose determinant must be zero in order to have non trivial solutions.Then, it will remain to check if there is at least one solution  where all components are squares, which might be tricky and leads to the following combinatorial question: if $V$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $K^n$, are there sufficient conditions to ensure that $V$ intersect $(K^2)^n$ non trivially ?

Comment: If the rank $r$ of the linear system is sufficiently large, it will be the case. In fact, if $K$ has $k$ elements and $n-r\geq 1$, the inequality $k^{n-r}+(\frac{k+1}{2})^n-1>k^n$  is enough to ensure the existence of a common zero. I don't know if you can have this inequality to hold in pratice....

Comment: @GreginGre: I do obtain a linear system, but the variables are then restricted to the squares of the ambient field. Furthermore, the linear system has $m$ equations and $n$ variables (where $n\ge 2m$), there are no determinants here to be zero!

Comment: sorry. I rephrase: the rank needs to be nonzero.

Comment: And i know that the coordinates of  a solution need to be squares. See my next comment.

Comment: (1) I suppose "the rank needs to be nonzero" needs to be "the number of variables $n$ exceeds the rank", correct? (2) I do not know how you derived the condition with $k^{n-r}$ etc but, say, for $k=3$ it cannot hold except for some degenerate cases where the rank is $0$ or $n$ is extremely small, agree?

Comment: By rank, i mean the rank of the linear system. But I agree that the combinatorial quesqtion seems to be as difficult as the originial question, so I don't think this approach will be fruitful.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems to me that $n>2m$ is the best we can do in general. Let $Q(x,y)$ be a bivariate form that vanishes only trivially. For example, we can choose $Q$ to be the norm form of the quadratic extension of $K$.

It follows that for all the forms
$$Q_i(x_1,\ldots,x_{2m}):=Q(x_{2i-1},x_{2i}),$$
$i=1,2,\ldots,m$,
vanish simultaneously only when $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_{2m}=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in fact I am not surprised that $n>2m$ is best possible. The point is, the criteria need not depend on $n$ and $m$ only. My question actually is: What condition(s) guarantee that $Q_i$ have a common nontrivial zero?

Comment: Ok. That is, indeed, a more interesting question. The first thing that comes to mind would be to look at the projective variety defined as the zero locus of the forms. Weil conjectures and all that. However, there will be severe geometric difficulties. Identifying an irreducible component for starters.

Comment: Difficult to believe this has not been studied...

Comment: I'm sure it has been studied! There are famous cases like the Segre embedding of a product of projective spaces into a higher dimensional space, defined by quadratic equations just like here. I don't know but I guess it quickly becomes difficult. Have you looked at the case of two forms and three variables. I'm fairly sure that has been studied exhaustively.

Comment: "Have you looked at the case of two forms and three variables?" I did. This is possible (say, $Q_1=x^2+y^2$ and $Q_2=x^2+y^2+2z^2$), but this does not contribute much to my understanding of the problem.