# Finding a unit vector $v$ that makes only one quadratic form vanish

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, generalized-eigenvector

I was reading a proof on the non-convexity (even locally) of loss landscape in high-dimensional neural networks. Specifically, in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.00307.pdf), it seems like the proof of proposition 2 at some point uses the following fact:

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ be symmetric matrices. Suppose that $\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq n$ and that $\operatorname{rank}(B) > 2n$. Then we can always find a unit vector $v$ such that $v^{\intercal}Av = 0$ but $v^{\intercal}Bv \neq 0$.

Is there a reason we should expect such a $v$ to exist? If so, is the condition $\operatorname{rank}(B) > 2n$ necessary? Or is it just sufficient? [Simultaneous vanishing of quadratic forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3882411/simultaneous-vanishing-of-quadratic-forms) seems to be similar but not quite the same thing, and I wasn't able to find anything else about this. Any insight into this would be appreciated!

Edit:

Here's what I've come up with thus far.

The problem is equivalent to showing that there exists a vector $v$ such that $v\in null(A)\cap col(B)$. This is equivalent to showing that there is a zero eigenvalue to the generalized eigenvector problem:
$$    Av = \lambda Bv   $$
With $\lambda = 0$. Let $U = null(A)$, $V = col(B)$. Since $rank(A) \leq n$, $dim(U) > m-n$ and $dim(V) > n$. Thus,
$$    dim(U+V) = dim(U) + dim(V) - dim(V\cap U)
$$Since $dim(U + V) \leq m$ and $dim(U) + dim(V) > m$, then $dim(V \cap U) \geq 1$, showing that $V \cap U \neq \emptyset$.